# 4.10 Lab: Remove gray from RGB

Tags: python

Given integers values for red green and blue. Subtract the gray from each value

I’ve been having trouble trying to get this problem right. Can someone please help me?

Comment: "_Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._" See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Actually in RGB `[0, 0, 0]` is black, `[255, 255, 255]` is white and all other combinations of numbers are either gray or colorful. If all 3 number are equal - that is going to be some shade of gray. If numbers differ - it's going to be some other color (not gray).

So gray is not in each of those values (red, green and blue), it's in combination of those.

You can just replace all pixels with combinations of equal numbers except for `[0, 0, 0]` and `[255, 255, 255]` with some other color (like white or whatever).